# Is there a requirement about

Tags: word-usage

Does this phrase sound natural?

> Is there a requirement about [something]?

Comment: If you're unsure about *about*, you can use *concerning*.

Comment: What @CowperKettle said. Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=requirements+about%2Crequirements+concerning%2Ca+requirement+about%2Ca+requirement+concerning&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crequirements%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crequirements%20concerning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20requirement%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20requirement%20concerning%3B%2Cc0), we usually use ***concerning*** rather than ***about*** here. And since you don't know if there are *multiple* requirements, you should probably use the plural form.

Comment: What's wrong with about? 'Concerning' in this context is old-fashioned BrE business English: what the secretary says when you call to speak to the boss used to be "What is it concerning?".